# Taylor's polynomial generalization

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Let $f:[a, b] \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a n-times differentiable function on $[a, b]$ and define $T_{f, x_0, n}$ be its Taylor's polynomial of degree n centered at $x_0 \in [a, b]$. I have noticed that one of the main characteristics of this polynomial is to agree with $f$ at $x_0$ up to at least the n-th derivative, that is:
$$
T_{f, x_0, n}^{(m)}(x_0) = f^{(m)}(x_0), \forall m \leq n
$$
then, I would like to ask if:

> "Given a collection $\{(x_i, n_i)\}_{1 \leq i \leq r}$ of couples, with the first element being a real number on $[a, b]$ and the second one being any positive integer, such that $n_1 + n_2 + ... + n_r = n+1$, is there a polynomial of degree $\leq n$ which agrees with $f$ at $x_i$ up to at least the $n_i$-th derivative, $\forall i \leq r$?"

As always, every form of partecipation to this open question is highly appreciated and welcome!

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation

Comment: @MartinR thank you very much for the reference! However, it doesn't completely satisfy my question as it only deals with the case in which each point has the same multiplicity and it doesn't explicitly state that other cases are impossible.

Comment: From the Wikipedia article: “In a more general case, there is no need for m to be a fixed value; that is, some points may have more known derivatives than others. In this case the resulting polynomial has a degree less than the number of data points.” – Isn't that exactly what you are looking for?

Comment: I couldn't find and I am still searching for this line in the Wikipedia page, however I trust that what you are saying might be true, hence I will try to search for more information on Hermite's polynomial online.

Comment: It is hidden in parentheses in the second paragraph of “Statement of the problem.” Unfortunately, the Wikipedia article focuses mainly on the case case all multiplicities  are the same. (It is better formulated in the [German version](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermiteinterpolation#Hermiteinterpolation), if that helps :)